# Unable to download images , texts , videos from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebase-storage

I am unable to download data(images , texts , videos) all into one recycler view with multiple view types from Firebase. The screen is just blank .

Here is the class where I want to display the data

```
public class Literature extends AppCompatActivity {

private SlidrInterface slidr;
StorageReference storageRef;
String Storage_Path = "All_Uploads/";

// Creating DatabaseReference.
DatabaseReference databaseReference;

// Creating RecyclerView.
RecyclerView recyclerView;

// Creating RecyclerView.Adapter.
RecyclerView.Adapter adapter ;

// Creating Progress dialog
ProgressDialog progressDialog;

// Creating List of ImageUploadInfo class.
ArrayList<Model> list= new ArrayList();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_literature);

    storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
    slidr = Slidr.attach(this);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(Literature.this));
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(Literature.this);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Loading Images From Firebase.");
    progressDialog.show();
    databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("All_Uploads/Design/" );


    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot snapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()) {

                Model model = postSnapshot.getValue(Model.class);

                list.add(model);
            }

            adapter = new MultiViewTypeAdapter(list , getApplicationContext());

            recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

            // Hiding the progress dialog.
            progressDialog.dismiss();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            // Hiding the progress dialog.
            progressDialog.dismiss();

        }
    });

}
}
```

Here is the adapter class for the Recycler View

```
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private ArrayList<Model>dataSet;
Context mContext;
int total_types;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private boolean fabStateVolume = false;

public static class TextTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    CardView cardView;

    public TextTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
}

public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    ImageView image;

    public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);
    }
}

public static class VideoTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    public VideoTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.fab = (FloatingActionButton) itemView.findViewById(R.id.fab);
    }
}

public MultiViewTypeAdapter(ArrayList<Model>data, Context context) {
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext = context;
    total_types = dataSet.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Model.TEXT_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_type, parent, false);
            return new TextTypeViewHolder(view);
        case Model.IMAGE_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_type, parent, false);
            return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
        case Model.VIDEO_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_type, parent, false);
            return new VideoTypeViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (dataSet.get(position).type) {
        case 0:
            return Model.TEXT_TYPE;
        case 1:
            return Model.IMAGE_TYPE;
        case 2:
        return Model.VIDEO_TYPE;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    Model object = dataSet.get(listPosition);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.type) {
            case Model.TEXT_TYPE:
                ((TextTypeViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.text);

                break;
            case Model.IMAGE_TYPE:
                ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.text);
                ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).image.setImageResource(object.data);
                break;
            case Model.VIDEO_TYPE:


                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
}
```

Here is the Model class

```
public class Model {

public static final int TEXT_TYPE=0;
public static final int IMAGE_TYPE=1;
public static final int VIDEO_TYPE=2;

public int type;
public int data;
public String text;

public Model(int type, String text, int data)
{
    this.type=type;
    this.data=data;
    this.text=text;
}
}
```

My Database
[image]

Please help me to see where I am going wrong

Comment: can you add screenshot of your firebasedatabase structure ?

Comment: gs://creatives-4ebde.appspot.com/All_Uploads/Design/ This is where all the images/videos/texts are stores

Comment: Do not create your adapter in your onDataChange(). Create your adapter inside your onCreate(), set it as the recyclerview's adapter in onCreate() and update the list and call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). You are unnecessarily recreating the object and making the recycler-view redraw itself everytime the data changes when it doesn't need to.

Comment: @Steven making the above suggested changes is making no difference

Comment: Hi @Steven, if you create the adapter right away in the onCreate() method, you dont have yet an arraylist to fill any data into the recyclerview, thats why you can initialize it inside onDataChanged after getting the data. You can do it in your onCreateView by modifying the getItemCount from the Adapter to return 0 if the array is empty. But at this case, the OP is just returning the current size of the array wich could throw an exception if the adapter is initialized inside the onCreate() method

Comment: OP, can you upload your database structure ?

Comment: @GastónSaillén That String is never used , all my uploads are in All_Uploads/Design/

Comment: @GastónSaillén That is why you give it an empty arraylist in onCreate() and only modify the arraylist inside onDataChanged().